# Adding Text and defined placement to a label in SLD (from QML(QGIS))

Tags: qgis, labeling, sld, qml, qgis-3

I've created a beautiful **rule-based Labeling** format in QGIS 3.12.

1) I have **added text** to the labels.

- for example using the value : **'Beton'**
- then the word Beton is added to the line

2) I also used **placement, data defined, coordinate X, coordinate Y**:

- endpoint:
- `x(line_interpolate_point($geometry,$length-5))`
- `y(line_interpolate_point($geometry,$length-5))`
- beginpoint:
- `x(line_interpolate_point($geometry,5))`
- `y(line_interpolate_point($geometry,5))`

When I save the layer style to SLD, it seems lot's of info is missing, and not being saved to the SLD.

In the picture you see the difference in the labels.

***How can I add some 'own'text and placement to the label in SLD 
(f.e. using the application Notepad++ and add text to it)? 
Is there anyone, with experience, what to write/add in de Notepad-file?***
[image]

Comment: Why not save it as a QML file?

Comment: can you add some of the SLD file?